# If a Login is not granted the db_ddladmin role on a database, but is individually granted CREATE VIEW on it, will they still be denied?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, permissions, logins, role

Since SQL Server permissions work as "deny first", I was wondering if that applies downward to individual permissions that are granted, if the parent permission isn't granted e.g. db_ddladmin is not granted but CREATE VIEW is for the Login.

Comment: you can just try this out and post the results :-)

Comment: @KinShah True, but in lieu of setting up my own development server at the moment, let's pretend I don't have access to set permissions. Any chance you know if my assumption is correct? :)

Comment: Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MyView, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
The specified schema name "dbo" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

SQL2016 Dev

Comment: `db_ddladmin` is not a "parent permission" it's a legacy role from the early days of SQL Server.  CREATE VIEW's "parent permission" is ALTER on the DATABASE.  To create a view a user requires the CREATE VIEW database permission and ALTER on the target schema.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Is it Microsoft's recommendation to not use those predefined roles available in the User Mapping GUI when setting database permissions for a login? If so, what's the alternative that is recommended?... creating custom roles?